# .NET Core - How to verfiy a ECDSA signature with named curve

Tags: c#, .net-core, ecdsa

I try to verfiy a signature with the named curve `secP256k1` and a public key in a byte array. I don't know how to add the public key to my `ECDsaCng` object. The hash of the data is a SHA256 hash.

```
static byte[] publicKey = new byte[] {
    0x04, 0xD3, ..., 0x20
};

public static bool VerifySignature(byte[] hash, byte[] signature)
{
    using (ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng(ECCurve.CreateFromFriendlyName("secP256k1")))
    {
        // How to add the public key?

        bool result = dsa.VerifyHash(hash, signature);

        return result;
    }
}
```

I tried to use `ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo`, but I get the exception **"ASN1 corrupted data"**

```
public static bool VerifySignature(byte[] hash, byte[] signature)
{
    using (ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng(ECCurve.CreateFromFriendlyName("secP256k1")))
    {
        int bytesRead;

        dsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(publicKey, out bytesRead);

        bool result = dsa.VerifyHash(hash, signature);

        return result;
    }
}
```

I hope anyone have an idea to solve the problem or could show me a different way.

Comment: The key format determines how the key is passed to `ECDsaCng`. `ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()` applies to a public key in SPKI (or X.509) format that is DER encoded. What format has your key? If it is a _raw_ key, you can create an `ECPoint` and with this `ECParameters` which can be passed directly to `ECDsaCng.Create()`.

Comment: @Topaco: That helped me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution looks like this:

```
public static bool VerifySignature(byte[] hash, byte[] signature)
{
    var dsa = ECDsa.Create(new ECParameters
    {
        Curve = ECCurve.CreateFromFriendlyName("secP256k1"),
        Q =
        {
            X = publicKey.Take(32).ToArray(),
            Y = publicKey.Skip(32).ToArray()
        }
    });

    bool result = dsa.VerifyHash(hash, signature);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the examples on the [ECDsaCng](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsacng?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), they have the receiver / your verify

```
public class Bob
{
    public byte[] key;

    public void Receive(byte[] data, byte[] signature)
    {
        using (ECDsaCng ecsdKey = new ECDsaCng(CngKey.Import(key, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob)))
        {
            if (ecsdKey.VerifyData(data, signature))
                Console.WriteLine("Data is good");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Data is bad");
        }
    }
}
```

My assumption is that your "dsa" can be instantiated with the other overload taking

```
CngKey.Import(publicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob)
```

as opposed to creating a new curve.

Comment: I know the example, but I have no idea how to use the named curve in that context

Comment: If you can use `CngKeyBlobFormat.EccFullPublicBlob`, then the curve parameters are included in the key information.

Comment: Hmm ok. But how can I create a key in an `EccFullPublicBlob`-format with my existing public key and the named curve? The curve is probably not so common.

Comment: You do not need to make a new public key as you want to verify that the digital signature is appropriate for the current public key and provided data hash.